# Android Paint PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR drawing black color on my view

Tags: android, image, paint

I want to implement eraser for my painting app . I am able to erase with the following code

```
 paint.setColor(0x00000000);
 paint.setAlpha(0x00);
```

But after erasing when you start painting again it does not paint properly so any idea to erase paint please suggest.

Comment: show your code... and have you seen FingerPaing example in API Demos..???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the below code.

```
      paint.setAlpha(0xFF);//transperent color
      paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));//clear the draw
```

Also have a look at the sample FingerPaint.java in the api demos under the folder graphics.

```
 setAlpha(int a)
```

Helper to setColor(), that only assigns the color's alpha value, leaving its r,g,b values unchanged.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html. Have a look a the 
documentation.

Edit:

Also check this

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=54105#c1

Comment: @Dnyaneshwar Wadghane try the above.

Comment: Unfortunately this draws a black color

Comment: Ok I found the answer! To achieve not black but transparent result you should firstl draw on another bitmap. Please read a comment here :https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=54105#c1

Answer (score 4):

I had same issue.

Need to set view's **setLayerType**.

```
yourView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

You can set it in constructor or by view's object.

Its done.

Answer (score -1):

This is should resolve this issue

```
private void touch_move(float x, float y){
    float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
    float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
    if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
        mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX) / 2, (y + mY) / 2);

        mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
        mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
        mPath.reset();
        mPath.moveTo(mX, mY);

        mX = x;
        mY = y;
    }
}
```

in touch_up() change it to:

```
private void touch_up() {

     mPath.reset();
}
```

Comment: I've tried this code in fingerpaint.java in API Demos and this works, but the problem is the smoothness of the pointer is not that great, probably because we are drawing the whole surface while moving the finger and then resetting the path.

Comment: It's working fine on a lot of devices, just try on other device (deferent OS and hardwire), also in your touch_start() put only this code: mPath.reset();
  mPath.moveTo(x, y);
  mX = x;
  mY = y;