# Black rect PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR in ViewGroup

Tags: android, canvas, drawing, porter-duff

I created a view which can scroll horizontal(via ViewGroup). On the left side I have image(kind of a title) for row. When I scroll my view to left, my items move under row's title. Because I have transparent background on title, I see items which under this title. I want to remove part of items which under the title. 
I tried to draw rects, via Paint with PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR, inside drawChild method, before drawing title. As result I had  black rects under the title.
I found some same questions, but in other context:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=54105#c1

[Android Paint PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR drawing black color on my view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15546342/android-paint-porterduff-mode-clear-drawing-black-color-on-my-view)

But I didn't find solution for this problem. As I understood some other bitmap has to be drew before using PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR. In my case I can't do this. Can I erase(in my case make transparent) some rect at my view?

**EDIT:**

```
@Override
protected boolean drawChild(Canvas canvas, View child, long drawingTime) {
    if(isTitle(child)){
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));

        Rect rect=new Rect(child.getLeft(),child.getTop(),child.getRight(),child.getBottom());

        canvas.drawRect(rect,paint);
    }
    return super.drawChild(canvas, child, drawingTime);
}
```

Also I saw somewhere this method, but it didn't change my layout at all:

```
@Override
protected boolean drawChild(Canvas canvas, View child, long drawingTime) {
    if(isTitle(child)){
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));

        Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(child.getWidth(), child.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        canvas.drawBitmap(b, child.getLeft(),child.getTop(), paint);
        b.recycle();
    }
    return super.drawChild(canvas, child, drawingTime);
}
```

**EDIT 2**. Tried saveLayer:

```
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));

        RectF rect=new RectF(child.getLeft(),child.getTop(),child.getRight(),child.getBottom());
        int a = canvas.saveLayer(rect, paint, Canvas.ALL_SAVE_FLAG);
        canvas.drawRect(rect,paint);
        canvas.restoreToCount(a);
```

**EDIT 3**

[image]

I have view which can scroll to left, right, up and down. This view contains 2 type of headers on top and on left side and I have items which can be different sizes. When I add all this items to view I add items first after that I add headers, in this case headers will be always drawn in front of items. And when user scroll left/top, items will be go to left/top side, but header will stay on their position and this item will be under the headers. When I had background for headers, it was ok, because user didn't see items under headers, but now I don't have background and user sees items under the headers. That's why I tried to use drawChild(which calls for every item) to erase part of items which under headers. But if I use

```
canvas.saveLayer(null, null, Canvas.ALL_SAVE_FLAG);                       
draw_whatever_you_want(canvas); 
canvas.drawRect(rect, clearPaint); 
canvas.restore();
```

I have to use it for all items. My code in drawChild

```
@Override
protected boolean drawChild(Canvas canvas, View child, long drawingTime) {
    if(!isTitle(child)){
        int left   = child.getLeft();
        int top    = child.getTop();
        int width  = getLeftHeaderWidth();
        int height = getTopHeaderHeight();
        if(left < width) {
            RectF rect = new RectF(0, 0, width, getHeight());
            canvas.saveLayer(null, null, Canvas.ALL_SAVE_FLAG);
            boolean result = super.drawChild(canvas, child, drawingTime);
            canvas.drawRect(rect, mClearPaint);
            canvas.restore();
            return result;
        } else if(top < height) {
            RectF rect = new RectF(0, 0, getWidth(), height);
            canvas.saveLayer(null, null, Canvas.ALL_SAVE_FLAG);
            boolean result = super.drawChild(canvas, child, drawingTime);
            canvas.drawRect(rect, mClearPaint);
            canvas.restore();
            return result;
        } else{
            return super.drawChild(canvas, child, drawingTime);
        }
    }else {
        return super.drawChild(canvas, child, drawingTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: As I remember, drawing with porterduff's modes require drawing on separate bitmap (not on canvas directly) and then on canvas. Can you show us some code?

Comment: @SemyonDanilov yes of course, I added my code

Comment: dont call any `Bitmap#createBitmap`, just use `saveLayer`

Comment: @pskink I tried saveLayer but it didn't help. Meybe I did it wrong, please look at my edit 2 I showed how I used it.

Comment: `canvas.saveLayer(null, null, Canvas.ALL_SAVE_FLAG); draw_whatever_you_want(canvas); canvas.drawRect(rect, clearPaint); canvas.restore();` where clearPaint is a Paint with xfermode == PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR)

Comment: @pskink Ok, I tried this method, it works but it became too slow because in this case I have to work with every item inside onDrawItem. I want to remove all none needed part in one move(In my case when I run into first title). Is there any ability to do that?

Comment: onDrawItem? what onDrawItem? post your whole custom ViewGroup

Comment: @pskink Sorry, I called it wrong it's drawChild where I do this work with canvas. I can't show you all my ViewGroup, but I tried to explain main idea in Edit 3.

Comment: why dont you override `dispatchDraw` where you can `clipRect` then call `super` and finaly draw your headers? no need for clearing anything...

Comment: @pskink It's exactly what I was looking for. Add it as an answer and I will confirm it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think what you are trying in `@Override protected boolean drawChild` is not a best thing, i would simply do the following:

```
@Override
protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.save(); // it saves the current clip, if not use CLIP_SAVE_FLAG
    canvas.clipRect(childrenRect)
    super.dispatchDraw(canvas); // draw your clipped children
    canvas.restore(); // now no clip
    draw_your_headers(canvas);
}
```